AOSP Cuttlefish orchestrator: How to create a host with local Android Image?
I was working hosting Android on my PC with Cuttlefish docker orchestrator and cvdr tool.
I followed the instruction given on https://github.com/google/cloud-android-orchestration/blob/main/docs/cvdr.md
And ran the command:
CVDR_USER_CONFIG_PATH=cvdr.toml \
./cvdr \
--host=${HOST_NAME} \
--branch=aosp-main \
--build_target=aosp_cf_x86_64_phone-trunk_staging-userdebug \
--auto_connect=false \
create

It worked.
However I want to start the host with my local Android image. Is this possible? If so how?
Thanks in advance!
I have also tried creating cvd without using docker and it also worked, say the unzipped image and cvd package is at <cvd_folder>
I tried creating cvd host with the following command:
CVDR_USER_CONFIG_PATH=cvdr.toml ./cvdr --local_images_srcs=<cvd_folder> --local_bootloader_src=<cvd_folder>/bootloader --local_cvd_host_pkg_src=<cvd_folder> --auto_connect=false create


Is this the correct command?
However I got the result as:
Creating Host........................................ OK
Uploading "bootloader"............................... Failed
failed to create cvd: stat ~/projects/instant_play/cuttlefish_image/bootloader: no such file or directory

Please advise.
Thanks!
